# how to detect if android device screen facing down\up\towards user using the sensors?

Tags: android, android-sensors

i need to find out the device orientation, however i must do it after data sample from the sensors is done and not waiting for an event to happen. 
i saw this code:

```
float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
float[] inclinationMatrix = new float[9];
float[] accelerometer; // values from sensor
float[] magnetic; // values from sensor
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, inclinationMatrix, 
accelerometer, magnetic) 
int inclination = (int) 
Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(rotationMatrix[8])));
if (inclination < 90)
{
  // face up
 }

if (inclination > 90)
 {
   // face down
  }
```

but the  accelerometer, magnetic arguments must me initlized. 
please help me out

Comment: check this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/detect-phone-flipping.html

Comment: Face down: 9 < z < 10
Face up: -10 < z < -9

Comment: @K.Sopheak you missed a bit, Face up is 9 < z < 10, face down is -10 < z < -9